# Azure Active Directory Access Token from Id Token

Tags: azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I'm using webView to build a mobile app. It means we're writing in HTML/JS hosted locally (file system), receiving data from APIs. Using [`ADAL.js`](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/) I received an `id_token`, trying to use it to get an authentication token, as [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj710106.aspx) results in a `401 Unauthorized`.

Is some configuration missing?

Request:

```
POST https://myAMS.azure-mobile.net/login/aad HTTP/1.1
Host: myAMS.azure-mobile.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1264
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, */*; q=0.01
Origin: file://
Authorization: Bearer ey...Ww
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; en-us; Nexus 4 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2307.2 Mobile Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

access_token=ey...Ww
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Service"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2015 10:47:45 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an audience mismatch. ADAL.JS obtains an id_token via implicit flow, which requires to identify the target resource by its clientID (a GUID). I am not in the mobile services team, but I assume they expect in the incoming token the app ID URI instead. You need to get an access token in order to get an audience other than the clientID. The asmple in https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-WebAPI-AngularJS-DotNet shows you how.
Disclaimer: ADAL.JS is not designed to be used in a web view. You might find its use difficult in that scenario. For those cases, we provide a Cordova plugin: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/04/06/adal-plugin-for-apache-cordova-deep-dive/

Comment: What if we're not using cordova?

Comment: If you are building everything from scratch, you might have challenges. The ADAL Cordova plugin leverages the ADAL native libraries for each platforms, which in turn implement sophisticated token caching and acquisition logic. If you simply use ADAL JS, or fork it to adapt it to work in a web view, you'll lose all those features - as the web view is sandboxed away from the actual device. Let me stress this: you can use ADAL JS in a non-SPA scenario, but you should expect bumps as it is not the setup it has been designed for.

Comment: We're accessing native, but through a different engine (internal). Any example that doesn't require going through a bunch of Angular?...

Comment: The sample in https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-jQuery-DotNet does not require angular, but of course it remains focused on the library's intended usage (web hosted spa)